# Very Good Free Lossless/Lossy Video Encoding For Editing on Windows 7 (regarding fraps recordings)

Tags: video, editing, codec, avid

I am looking for a very good method to encode video recorded with fraps in 1080p into an intermediate format which I can edit in Avid Studio. Most video files load up into Avid, as far as I know, but Fraps recordings isn't one of them (on my computer at least). So I'm here to ask if anyone here knows of a guide, or is willing to write one as an answer on how to do that.

Assume that I have no previous codecs installed apart from the included ones with windows 7 home premium.

My problem, if anyone is interested, is that when I load fraps videos into avid, I get audio, but no video. I don't know much about video editing or encoding, only what I have learned in the past 2 weeks. Please feel free to link me to websites with required theory(I will read it), but I'm really just looking for a tutorial right now.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/) to convert your FRAPS files. Just drag the clip into the window, select video from the top menu -> compression. Change the codec to Avid AVI Codec 2.0d2 and then configure it to your desired resolution. BAM! The outputted files should work.

You can also try MediaCoder and XVid

Comment: ok, so I've used virtualdub quite a bit in recent times, I have heard of people using the Avid AVI Codec 2.0d2... one big problem... I don't know how to get the Avid AVI Codec, can you provide an installation instruction link? XVid is out, it crashes on me when I try to playback the encoded file, and I haven't heard of "MediaCoder", will check that out in the future.

Comment: Try media coder. Ill try the virtualdub install and give you a guide.